# Combine multiple vector fields for approximate nearest neighbor search

Tags: nlp, vector-space-models, ann

I have multiple vector fields in one collection. My use-case is to find similar sentences in similar contexts. The sentences and contexts are encoded to float vectors. Therefore, I have one vector for the sentence and another vector for the context (surrounding text). I would like take both vectors in consideration to find similar sentences. Unfortunately, most approximate nearest neighbor (ann) search libraries only support to search for one field. I have tried to use PostgreSQL with the cube extension to filter by multiple vector similarities. Unfortunately, the number of vectors (100M) are too high for PostgreSQL.

**Questions:**

1. Is there a possibility to combine multiple vector fields for approximate nearest neighbor search?
2. Is it also possible to weight the relevance of each vector field for the search?

Answer (score 1):

One alternative is to re-encode the sentences and context together into the same vector space. This can be done with doc2vec or [StarSpace](https://github.com/facebookresearch/StarSpace).

If the sentences and contexts are in the same vector space, any approximate nearest neighbor (ann) search libraries could work.

Comment: I have a somehow similar question on the matter, but related to qdrant. Can you please take a look at it and guide me if you can?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78095982/having-one-vector-column-for-multiple-text-columns-on-qdrant